How to pick a lot of files at once on android using flutter?
how can I select many files, like 2000, at once on Android using Flutter? Until now, I've been using the following code with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and it worked well:
await for (FileSystemEntity entity in directory.list(recursive: true, followLinks: false)) {
if (entity is File && entity.path.toLowerCase().endsWith('.txt')) 
  {
    files.add(entity);
  }
}

However, I don't want to use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE anymore because it's no longer allowed by Google at least for this reason. I tried using FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(), but it didn't work due to the large number of files.
I also tried this code:
Saf saf = Saf('/storage/emulated/0');
bool? isGranted = await saf.getDirectoryPermission(isDynamic: true);
if (isGranted != null && isGranted) 
  { 
    List<String>? paths = await saf.getFilesPath();
  }

But I encountered the error (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13) and couldn't read the files. However, if I try to write a new file to the same path, it works fine.
The used permissios are:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>

I would really appreciate any helpful advice.
